# "calculation timed out." error when performing principal component analysis on Sentinel data

Tags: google-earth-engine, pca

When I perform principal component analysis on Sentinel data, the following error always appears: "calculation timed out." I wonder whether my research area is too large or there are too many pixels in the image? Here is my code.

```
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}
var composite = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2021-07-01','2021-12-31')
                  //.filterBounds(cs)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',5))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .mean();
print(composite)
var boundary = ee.FeatureCollection("users/LiLiy/KONGJIAN")

function PCA(maskedImage){
  var image = maskedImage.unmask()
  var scale = 20;
  var region = boundary;
  var bandNames = image.bandNames();
  // Mean center the data to enable a faster covariance reducer
  // and an SD stretch of the principal components.
  var meanDict = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: scale,
    maxPixels: 1e9,
    bestEffort: true,
     tileScale: 16
  });
  var means = ee.Image.constant(meanDict.values(bandNames));
  var centered = image.subtract(means);
  // This helper function returns a list of new band names.
  var getNewBandNames = function(prefix) {
    var seq = ee.List.sequence(1, bandNames.length());
    return seq.map(function(b) {
      return ee.String(prefix).cat(ee.Number(b).int());
    });
  };
  // This function accepts mean centered imagery, a scale and
  // a region in which to perform the analysis.  It returns the
  // Principal Components (PC) in the region as a new image.
  var getPrincipalComponents = function(centered, scale, region) {
    // Collapse the bands of the image into a 1D array per pixel.
    var arrays = centered.toArray();
    
    // Compute the covariance of the bands within the region.
    var covar = arrays.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.centeredCovariance(),
      geometry: region,
      scale: scale,
      maxPixels: 1e9,
      bestEffort: true,
      tileScale: 16
    });
     // Get the 'array' covariance result and cast to an array.
    // This represents the band-to-band covariance within the region.
    var covarArray = ee.Array(covar.get('array'));

    // Perform an eigen analysis and slice apart the values and vectors.
    var eigens = covarArray.eigen();

    // This is a P-length vector of Eigenvalues.
    var eigenValues = eigens.slice(1, 0, 1);
    // Compute Percentage Variance of each component
    var eigenValuesList = eigenValues.toList().flatten()
    var total = eigenValuesList.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
    var percentageVariance = eigenValuesList.map(function(item) {
      return (ee.Number(item).divide(total)).multiply(100).format('%.2f')
    })
    // This will allow us to decide how many components capture
    // most of the variance in the input
    print('Percentage Variance of Each Component', percentageVariance)
    // This is a PxP matrix with eigenvectors in rows.
    var eigenVectors = eigens.slice(1, 1);
    // Convert the array image to 2D arrays for matrix computations.
    var arrayImage = arrays.toArray(1);

    // Left multiply the image array by the matrix of eigenvectors.
    var principalComponents = ee.Image(eigenVectors).matrixMultiply(arrayImage);
        // Turn the square roots of the Eigenvalues into a P-band image.
    var sdImage = ee.Image(eigenValues.sqrt())
      .arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('sd')]);

    // Turn the PCs into a P-band image, normalized by SD.
    return principalComponents
      // Throw out an an unneeded dimension, [[]] -> [].
      .arrayProject([0])
      // Make the one band array image a multi-band image, [] -> image.
      .arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('pc')])
      // Normalize the PCs by their SDs.
      .divide(sdImage);
  };
  var pcImage = getPrincipalComponents(centered, scale, region);
  return pcImage.mask(maskedImage.mask());
}
var pca = PCA(composite).select(['pc1', 'pc2', 'pc3'])
var composite = composite.addBands(pca)  
Map.addLayer(pca, {bands: ['pc1', 'pc2', 'pc3']}, 'pca')
Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: ['red', 'green', 'blue']}, 'pca_Composite')
```

Comment: Hard to say since you haven't shared or given coordinates for the asset `'users/LiLiy/KONGJIAN'`. But with a small area, your code runs until the final `Map.addLayer(composite, etc...)` and the fails as `composite` doesn't have a band named `red` - `pca_Composite: Layer error: Image.visualize: No band named 'red'. Available band names: [B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B8A, B9, B11, B12, AOT, WVP, SCL, TCI_R, TCI_G, TCI_B, MSK_CLDPRB, MSK_SNWPRB, QA10, QA20, QA60, pc1, pc2, pc3].`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, probably it is a scale issue. If you change scale to 200 (or higher; eventually) you could get a result. For testing my suggestion, I used an arbitrary area in USA and my suggested scale of 200. I also changed visualization parameters.

My [code](https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/4c60433e5a156e3349e80b01d316b6f2) looks as follows:

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-104.26459194118954, 36.152899064844156],
          [-104.26459194118954, 33.94056652040424],
          [-99.65033412868954, 33.94056652040424],
          [-99.65033412868954, 36.152899064844156]]], null, false);

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}
var composite = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2021-07-01','2021-12-31')
                  //.filterBounds(cs)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',5))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .mean();
print(composite);
var boundary = geometry; //ee.FeatureCollection("users/LiLiy/KONGJIAN")

function PCA(maskedImage){
  var image = maskedImage.unmask();
  var scale = 200;
  var region = boundary;
  var bandNames = image.bandNames();
  // Mean center the data to enable a faster covariance reducer
  // and an SD stretch of the principal components.
  var meanDict = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: scale,
    maxPixels: 1e9,
    bestEffort: true,
     tileScale: 16
  });
  var means = ee.Image.constant(meanDict.values(bandNames));
  var centered = image.subtract(means);
  // This helper function returns a list of new band names.
  var getNewBandNames = function(prefix) {
    var seq = ee.List.sequence(1, bandNames.length());
    return seq.map(function(b) {
      return ee.String(prefix).cat(ee.Number(b).int());
    });
  };
  // This function accepts mean centered imagery, a scale and
  // a region in which to perform the analysis.  It returns the
  // Principal Components (PC) in the region as a new image.
  var getPrincipalComponents = function(centered, scale, region) {
    // Collapse the bands of the image into a 1D array per pixel.
    var arrays = centered.toArray();
    
    // Compute the covariance of the bands within the region.
    var covar = arrays.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.centeredCovariance(),
      geometry: region,
      scale: scale,
      maxPixels: 1e9,
      bestEffort: true,
      tileScale: 16
    });
     // Get the 'array' covariance result and cast to an array.
    // This represents the band-to-band covariance within the region.
    var covarArray = ee.Array(covar.get('array'));

    // Perform an eigen analysis and slice apart the values and vectors.
    var eigens = covarArray.eigen();

    // This is a P-length vector of Eigenvalues.
    var eigenValues = eigens.slice(1, 0, 1);
    // Compute Percentage Variance of each component
    var eigenValuesList = eigenValues.toList().flatten();
    var total = eigenValuesList.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());
    var percentageVariance = eigenValuesList.map(function(item) {
      return (ee.Number(item).divide(total)).multiply(100).format('%.2f');
    });
    // This will allow us to decide how many components capture
    // most of the variance in the input
    print('Percentage Variance of Each Component', percentageVariance);
    // This is a PxP matrix with eigenvectors in rows.
    var eigenVectors = eigens.slice(1, 1);
    // Convert the array image to 2D arrays for matrix computations.
    var arrayImage = arrays.toArray(1);

    // Left multiply the image array by the matrix of eigenvectors.
    var principalComponents = ee.Image(eigenVectors).matrixMultiply(arrayImage);
        // Turn the square roots of the Eigenvalues into a P-band image.
    var sdImage = ee.Image(eigenValues.sqrt())
      .arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('sd')]);

    // Turn the PCs into a P-band image, normalized by SD.
    return principalComponents
      // Throw out an an unneeded dimension, [[]] -> [].
      .arrayProject([0])
      // Make the one band array image a multi-band image, [] -> image.
      .arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('pc')])
      // Normalize the PCs by their SDs.
      .divide(sdImage);
  };
  var pcImage = getPrincipalComponents(centered, scale, region);
  return pcImage.mask(maskedImage.mask());
}
var pca = PCA(composite).select(['pc1', 'pc2', 'pc3']);
var composite = composite.addBands(pca);

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["B4","B3","B2"],
                     "min":0.03596875071525574,
                     "max":0.25026053190231323,
                     "gamma":1};

Map.centerObject(geometry, 8);
Map.addLayer(pca.clip(geometry), {bands: ['pc1', 'pc2', 'pc3']}, 'pca');
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(composite).clip(geometry), imageVisParam, 'pca_Composite');
```

After running it in GEE code editor, I got following result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, which is very helpful to me. However, when I expand the study area or add more features for principal component analysis, there will still be previous errors. Do I continue to increase the value of scale at this time? Will the value of scale affect the final result?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a scale issue. And the reason is because GEE provides a limited computation time for regular users. So, you can try a coarser scale for your outputs.